# How to get the Salvage Droid stages for the least bux?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I had about 650+ bux, but blew through them playing the Salvage Droid slots trying to get those stages. I think Kashyyyk was in the 2nd slot (at 15 bux a pop), and I must have wasted 345 bux but only have 2 wookies to show for it (not counting all the other crappy prizes).

I then used what remaining bux I had to rescan until Endor showed up in the 3rd slot (25 bux a pop), and I managed to get one of the Endor levels from there, along with 2 Ewoks and a rabbit-like creature.

I then saved my bux and had 75 when Endor showed up in the 3rd slot again. This time, in 3 spins, I got the remaining Endor level.

I'm still lacking the 2 Kashyyyk levels and the 2 Csilla levels, and since it's soooooo hard to get bux nowadays and so many places to spend it (dream jobbers holding out bux on you, and Decorator Droids not wanting to show up unless you bribe them), I would like to stretch my bux and know what's the most cost-efficient way to get those stages?

Also, does Kashyyyk still show up on your scans? Because I've only gotten Endor nowadays. I don't believe this is a limited event so I think Kashyyyk and Csilla should show up again, but they haven't for a while now and I'm getting a little worried.

So, for those who had gotten the Salvage Droid levels, how much bux did you spend (ballpark figure) to get them? What kind of Salvage Droid or which slot? Personally, I think spending bux anywhere but the last slot is a waste or maybe it was just dumb luck that i got those levels within a few spins...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing to "cheat" and spend some time on it, you can get all the levels for 25 bux apiece (or less if you're willing to spend more time).  I initially blew through 800 bux without getting a level so I got frustrated and started googling.  Here are instructions for Android based on what I found (sorry, you're on your own with iPhone).

Get the planet you want in the 25 bux slot (see note below), then:

1. Exit Tiny Death Star
2. Put your phone in Airplane Mode
3. Start Tiny Death Star
4. Send the 25-bux salvage droid and wait for return
5. Open the cargo.  If it's a level, goto step 6, otherwise goto step 7
6. Yay, you got something you wanted!

   - Collect the item
   - Press and hold power button and turn Airplane Mode off
   - Play for 5 min to resync with online servers
   - Goto step 1
7. Boo, you got junk!

   - Open the "Recent Apps" screen on your phone
   - Swipe TDS away
   - Turn Airplane Mode off and wait for Wifi or data to reconnect
   - Start TDS
   - You should get screen asking you to pick local or online, choose online
   - After game finishes loading, goto step 1 (or just re-enable Airplane and goto step 4)

So if you get a level, you continue playing and lose the 25 bux you spent. Otherwise you restore to your earlier state and it's like it never happened. :-) Of course you can also choose to keep the special bitizens or other cargo if you think they are worth 25 bux to you.

Note that you can use a similar process to rescan (using either the free scan or 5 bux) until you get the planet you want in the 25 bux slot.  You can also do this with the other slots but the chances of getting a level are a lot less so you just have to go through this more times.  Even at 25 bux, it will take you several hours to get all the levels this way.

Comment: Any iOS users have any luck with the above method? Pls post here if you successfully get the stages (for iOS users)

Comment: I thought I should let people know that this technique seems to have stopped working for me.  I am no longer given the choice of "local or on-line" when I restart the app with airplane mode off. The developers must have changed how things are handled when you play with no network connection.

Answer (score 2):

Kashyyyk will still show up, but honestly the way to get things for the least Bux is not to play their game; be patient, wait for the free rescans to put something useful in the highest slot, and send your one free droid a day. Nothing about this appears to be limited-time only, so don't let gambler's fallacies impoverish you.

I have received characters from the highest slot, only one level so far (from one of the other slots), and all manner of nonsense. But when you get the "You already have this prize" message, you should at least make a Bux profit if it's from the highest slot...

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the Kashyyyk level still shows up on the scans.  I just had it appear in the 25 Bux level so I spent 50 bux and received cooling coils and a Supply Officer.  I have yet to receive any of the levels from the Salvage Droid activity and I have spent over 600 bux just like you.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen all the areas show up in all three slots but I never get anything from them, blew 1800 now and refuse to purchase any more from the store, nothing but useless stuff from the probe droids, it's pure luck to get anything, at least the decorator droid quest is proving much more satisfying and haven't had to spend real money on that one.